# Angular.js ng-repeat :filter by numeric field

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying to apply a filter to a numeric field as follows:

```
ng-repeat="venue in venues | filter:{ regionId: regionId }"
```

however, if for example, the regionId is 2, it will return venues for regionId's 2, 12, 23 etc.

Can anyone please advise the best way to resolve this?

Comment: What about writing a custom filter ?

Comment: Will resort to that if I have to. It just feels like this should be feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) says:

> Usage
>
> In HTML Template Binding
>
> ```
> {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> comparator:   function(actual, expected) | true | undefined
>
> Comparator which is used in determining if the expected value (from the filter expression) and actual value (from the object in the array) should be considered a match.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> [...]
>
> true: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return angular.equals(expected, actual)}. this is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.

Comment: Thanks JB, but this use of strict is doing my head in. You will notice that the protractor test in the documentation doesn't actually work! I am trying to translate this into my code as follows: ng-repeat="venue in venues | filter:{ regionId: regionId } : true"

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is what I got to work:

```
ng-repeat="venue in venues | filter:{regionId:selectedRegionId}:true"
```

The problem is that the strict comparison only works for strings and not integer types. I had to convert regionId to a string first, but it made no difference what type selectedRegionId was.

Note also that the use of the strict comparator is Angular version-specific!

Comment: For me I didn't have to convert to string. The values I had were numeric from a Json object and the strict comparison worked.

Comment: I edited the plunkr to highlight the usage of the correct datatype, see the filter by id (don't forget to toggle strict filtering):
http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7aaMZzrMVBGMfrhL1aw?p=preview